# Use an existing GWT component in vaadin 21

Tags: gwt, vaadin, vaadin21

We have a pre-existing (vaadin 7) gwt component which we are looking to bring forward to vaadin 21.

We don't want to use the Multiplatform Runtime as the pricing is excessive.

In the end the gwt component just compiles to javascript so there must be someway of wiring it into vaadin 21?

The component is seriously non-trivial so we want to avoid having to redevelop it.

Comment: I think you will have to at least redevelop the connector part of the component, this isn't compatible. The other parts might be portable, but how browser support in GWT is in the future...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should look into GWT Exporter: https://code.google.com/archive/p/gwt-exporter/

Answer (score 2):

From an architectural point of view, what you need to be able to use a GWT component from something like Vaadin 21 is that the component needs to have its API exported as JavaScript.

If the component has a small API surface, then it might make sense to do that manually using JsInterop (or JSNI if that's what you have experience with).

If the API surface is bigger, then some additional tooling might be more appropriate.